# Multiple Regression: Spatial Covariate

Tags: multiple-regression, spatial

Im trying to fit a multiple regression model that predicts deaths from earthquakes using magnitude and location of epicenter as predictors.

I have no idea how to handle the spatial aspect ie the longitude and latitude for the epicenter and incorporate this probably into my model.

If anyone could point me in the right direction with a good book or suggestions for how to handle this I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Do you have a physical model that suggests the effects the earthquakes would have as a function of distance from the epicenter (and maybe type, intensity, and duration of the quake)?  This would, at least indirectly, suggest appropriate and effective models to evaluate.